# What am I doing wrong when multiplying binary numbers together?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, binary, binary-operations

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its applications 
[image]

I was able to get sum pretty easy.

I am trying to follow this example in the book to get the product of the two binary numbers 
[image]

Here's my work so far [image]

I got the expected output from my calculator windows application. Does anyone see what the issue is? The problem starts when I don't get 7 zeros separating the first two ones. What would you do with the end result, 8? I am still not sure about that.

Comment: Why do you have numbers such as "9" or "8" in carry? In binary, for example, $1+1+1+1 = 100$ so you should write $0$ as the result and have a carry of $10$, you should place the $0$ on the carry on the next left column, and the $1$ in the carry two columns on the left. I did the multiplication that way and I got the result $10000100000001$.

Comment: If you're going to keep asking homework problems, then please at least try to [format](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) them well.

Comment: @induktio thanks I keep that in mind

Comment: @LaurentHayez it cumulates, starting from the carry 2 in the fourth column

Comment: @NotAsCommitedAndroider It does not make sens to add binary numbers and have carries written in base 10. It would be like doing an addition in base 10 and have chinese symbols in the carries, what would they represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very easy way to get your desired product is to convert both numbers to base $10$ and *then* to multiply them and *then* to express that product in base $2$. It's not the cleanest thing to do in the world, but neither is your approach. Consider that
$$
(1000111)_2 = 1(2^6)+1(2^2)+1(2)+1 = 71,
$$
and
$$
(1110111)_2 = 1(2^6)+1(2^5)+1(2^4)+1(2^2)+1(2)+1 = 119.
$$
Thus, we have that 
$$
(1000111)_2 \cdot (1110111)_2 = 71\cdot 119 = 8449.
$$
Now simply convert $8449$ into base $2$:
$$
8449 = 1(2^{13})+1(2^8)+1 = (10000100000001)_2.
$$
Thus, we see that
$$
(1000111)_2 \cdot (1110111)_2 = (10000100000001)_2.
$$

Comment: Yeah much cleaner than what I had

Answer (score 4):

Okay let's take a simple example: suppose you want to add $(111)_2 + (111)_2 + (111)_2$. First of all, all the carries will be written in binary, and not in decimal. Here is how you should do that:

```
        1
Carry: 1101         
         111
        +111
        +111
        ----
       10101
```

**Explanation:** On the right most column, you first add $1+1+1=11_2$. So you note 1 in the result line and note $1$ as you first carry.
Then you add $1+1+1+1=100_2$, therefore you write one $0$ in the result line, and you have a carry of $10$. To handle that carry, you can simply write $10$ in the carry over two columns (that is the 0 will be above one column, and the one above the column on the left).
The next addition is $0+1+1+1=11_2$ so once again you write $1$ in the result line and carry $1$ (which I wrote above the $1$ from the preceding $10$) and the rest is easy.

Comment: This is the first *clear* explanation of how to do these excessive (layered?) carries after over an hour of searching this stack *and* the web. No one provides examples where you have to sum several 1s back to back like this. Thank you for being the only one to actually do so!

Comment: @ZeroKnight I'm glad it helped :-)